# @Crossorigin on root breaks when upgrading from Spring Boot 1.5.x to 2.0.x

Tags: spring-boot, cors

So I have a rest controller configured thus:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/po")
```

There's no security configured in this application, the @CrossOrigin is to allow me to hit the endpoint from a small piece of javascript inside a browser instead of Postman. (Safari fwiw).

It has run for ever in spring boot 1.5.x
I just upgraded to 2.0.3 and it stopped working.

A few seconds with the browser debugger gives me this little gem

```
Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true.
```

Literally the only change - from my perspective - was to upgrade the version. Google hasn't been my friend here, so I'm wondering if anyone else has hit this.

As an aside I tried adding a method level @CrossOrigin and that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh - answering my own question - but at least this way it'll get search indexed.

I found this : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12488

From that, this one small change fixes the problem: `@CrossOrigin(allowCredentials="true")`

Answer (score 0):

I think with Spring 5 they changed the default allowed origins of the `@CrossOrigin` and now you have to explicitly say `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` on class/method level.